# How to add color to a cell in an excel sheet using C# COM Interop

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

I'm using C# COM Interop to create and update Excel files on the fly. I used the below code. But I'm not sure how to add color to a particular cell. Please help me with the same.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excel_filename);
Excel.Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets.Add();
sh.Name = "TestSheet";
sh.Cells[1, "A"].Value2 = "SNO";
sh.Cells[2, "B"].Value2 = "A";
sh.Cells[2, "C"].Value2 = "1122";
wb.Close(true);
excel.Quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
  wb.Cells[row, clmn].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you also please let me know how to see the properties like .Interior.Color Because when I checked, those properties are run time. And also Can you let me know how to add width to the cell or fit the string passed in to the cell. Thank you.

Comment: Range.Rows.AutoFit();
Range.Columns.AutoFit();

Comment: Follow this link http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.3.0/SpreadsheetGear~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~AutoFit.html     or http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm